# C# : how to include .sdf database file and Crystal Reports while creating .exe in setup project?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, sql-server-ce

I've created an desktop application using c# language and in which I've used a `.sdf` (SQL Server CE database file) as local database and exporting the results into Crystal Reports.

**Problem(requirement)**

1. Want to include the `.sdf` file and Crystal Reports files into .exe
2. Can I include automatic installation of Crystal Reports setup into .exe itself? If so then how?

I've already developed whole application but needed some help while making .exe.

Does anyone have idea about this? Please help me in this. Thanks!

Comment: You should include them as embedded resources in any dir under your .exe project.

Comment: can you elaborate with steps? so that i can get better idea about your above statement? thanks!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 0):

https://www.sap.com/cmp/ft/crm-xm15-dwn-an009/typ.html

find the downloads. You have cr_vr_20 installation file as well as runtime for 64 and 32 bit versions.